# Regexp to parse Hy errors for Flycheck

Tags: regular-expressions, flycheck, rx

I'm trying to write a Flycheck checker definition based on [Hy](http://docs.hylang.org/en/latest/index.html), using the [API here](http://flycheck.readthedocs.org/en/latest/dev/extending.html#el.function.flycheck-define-checker). As part of that, I have to define a pattern for error matching. Now, Hy gives quite a large error spew, for example:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/hy", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('hy==0.10.1', 'console_scripts', 'hy')()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/hy/cmdline.py", line 305, in hy_main
    sys.exit(cmdline_handler("hy", sys.argv))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/hy/cmdline.py", line 293, in cmdline_handler
    return run_file(options.args[0])
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/hy/cmdline.py", line 194, in run_file
    import_file_to_module("__main__", filename)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/hy/importer.py", line 74, in import_file_to_module
    eval(ast_compile(_ast, fpath, "exec"), mod.__dict__)
  File "helloworld.hy", line 1, in <module>
    (prin "Hello world")
NameError: name 'prin' is not defined
```

The only part of interest to the checker is the very last bit:

```
  File "helloworld.hy", line 1, in <module>
    (prin "Hello world")
NameError: name 'prin' is not defined
```

So I need to write a `:error-patters` form that will match the following exactly:

1. A tab character
2. The string `File "`
3. The name of my file (Flycheck does this using `(file-name)`)
4. The string `", line` (with a terminating space)
5. The line number (Flycheck does this using `line`)
6. The string `, in <module>\n\t\t` (where `\n\t\t` is a newline followed by two tabs)
7. Whatever follows until the next newline (including that newline)
8. Whatever remains is the error message (which Flycheck matches with `(message)`)

So far, I have this:

```
:error-patterns ((error line-start "\tFile \"" (file-name) "\", line " line ", in <module>\n\t\t")) ;something more needs to go here
```

This gets me as far as step 6, but I'm not sure what to do for step 7, as I don't know `rx` at all. Any and all help would be very much appreciated, both by me and the fledgling Hy community.

Comment: Will `".*\n"` work?

Comment: why do you call it `:error-patters` instead of `:error-patterns`?

Comment: @wdkrnls: Because I can't spell. Fixing now.

Comment: Consider using `re-builder` (comes with Emacs, see `C-h f re-builder RET`) or [`helm-regexp`](http://tuhdo.github.io/helm-intro.html#sec-18) to build the regular expression.

Comment: Please write a dedicated program that statically analyzes the Hy code for (stylistic) issues and let it write parseable output to STDOUT instead of running the program and waiting for errors.

Comment: @wasamasa: Yeah, I *now* realize that's what I'll have to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure whether you can really parse that with regular expressions only.  I think you are better off with a custom `:error-parser`, i.e. a function that parses this error.

This function would insert the output into a temporary buffer, search forwards to search for occurrences of `Traceback …`, skip over all indented lines to extract the error message, and then search backwards to the first occurrence of `File "..."`:

```
(defun flycheck-parse-hy-traceback (output _checker _buffer)
  (with-temp-buffer
    ;; Insert output of Hy
    (insert output)
    (goto-char (point-min))

    (let (errors)
      ;; Search forward for the next traceback
      (while (re-search-forward "^Traceback" nil 'noerror)
        ;; Goto to the first line of the backtrace,…
        (forward-line 1)
        ;; …, and skip over indented lines, that is all lines of the backtrace up
        ;; to the error message
        (while (looking-at (rx line-start blank))
          (forward-line 1))
        ;; Extract the message
        (let ((message (buffer-substring-no-properties
                        (line-beginning-position) (line-end-position)))
              (end (point)))
          ;; Search backwards for the last error location
          (when (re-search-backward (rx line-start
                                        (one-or-more blank)
                                        "File \""
                                        (group-n 1 (one-or-more (not (any "\""))))
                                        "\", line "
                                        (group-n 2 (one-or-more digit)))
                                    nil 'noerror)
            ;; Extract the file name and the line, and create a new error object
            (push (flycheck-error-new :filename (match-string 1)
                                      :line (flycheck-string-to-number-safe
                                             (match-string 2))
                                      :level 'error
                                      :message message)
                  errors))
          ;; Move out of this error to continue searching for other errors
          (goto-char end)))
      errors)))
```

Then use `:error-parser flycheck-parse-hy-traceback` instead of `:error-patterns` in the definition of your syntax checker.

Besides, a **word of warning**:  It looks like your syntax checker **runs** Hy files to check them.  That's a bad idea, for many reasons, and you should really **not** do that, if there's any other way.

**Disclaimer:** I'm the Flycheck maintainer.